# Where is the documentation for cudaArray?

Tags: c++, cuda, documentation

I have greped through /usr/local/cuda/doc, gotten to the 4th page of Google results, checked the index of *CUDA By Example* and searched through [developer.download.nvidia.com](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/) to no avail.

There is a page on [cudaMallocArray](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/4_1/rel/toolkit/docs/online/group__CUDART__MEMORY_gf0689399573bd8a922351aae4d040349.html), which accepts cudaArray as an argument, however there is no link on that page to documentation about cudaArray itself.

Is cudaArray deprecated?  I can't find anything saying it is.  Is there any information on its use?

Comment: possible duplicate of [cudaArray vs. device pointer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14450029/cudaarray-vs-device-pointer)

Answer (score 3):

`cudaArray`s are a core part of CUDA and unlikely to go anywhere because they provide access to hardware that optimizes 2D texture sampling. They are described in the [Memory Management](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__MEMORY.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY) section of the [CUDA Runtime API documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/index.html). And they are introduced in the [CUDA C Programming Guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

Some example:
http://cuda-programming.blogspot.fr/2013/02/cuda-array-in-cuda-how-to-use-cuda.html

Other example:
[cudaArray simple example-- How to allocate 1D array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12542822/cudaarray-simple-example-how-to-allocate-1d-array)

Some information about CudAArray in the ending slides:
https://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CEYQFjAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.eecg.toronto.edu%2F~moshovos%2FCUDA08%2Fslides%2F008%2520-%2520Textures.ppt&ei=fjkmU-reMcTI0QXm5oGoCw&usg=AFQjCNHMccUExB5WrE6SibJ4MpQFynuuRw&sig2=fOkKFMq1GDRgtJMQaImgdg&bvm=bv.62922401,d.d2k

Hope this can help